# Ajax send selected data only

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have ajax code which is working only if i select option for all selects.

## Issue

```
Select box 1 (option selected)
Select Box 2 (option selected)
Select Box 3 (option didn't select)

result: code 500 (won't send data)

//////////////////////

Select Box 1 (option selected)
Select Box 2 (option selected)
Select Box 3 (option selected)

result: code 200 (sending data)
```

## Code

```
<script defer>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on("change", ".autosubspecifications", function() {
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var id = form.find('input[name="product_id"]').val();

      // An array to store the subspecifications values.
      var spec_array = [];

      // A loop to go through all them.
      form.find('select.autosubspecifications option:selected').each(function(){
        spec_array.push($(this).val());
      });

      console.log(id);
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '{{ url('admin/spacssendto') }}',
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': id,
          'subspecifications': spec_array,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert('Specifications added successfully.');
          console.log($(this));
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

#### What I want

Is to send data as they selected if i choose options for two or even one of my select boxes get code 200, not to be forced to select values for all my selects.

Any idea?

## Update

here is my back-end (controller)

```
public function spacssendto(Request $request)
{
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'product_id' => 'required',
          'subspecifications' => 'required',
        ));
        $product = Product::find($request->product_id);
        $product->subspecifications()->sync($request->subspecifications, false);
}
```

**Sync method**

What my sync method does, is to store `product_id` and `subspecification_id` into table named `product_subspecification`

`database`

[image: one]

`how data are passing currently`

[image: two]

#### Error

as my network response (when i'm not select option from all my select boxes) i get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`u641790295_kargr`.`product_subspecification`, CONSTRAINT `product_subspecification_subspecification_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`subspecification_id`) REFERENCES `subspecifications` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `product_subspecification` (`product_id`, `subspecification_id`) values (21, ))
```

## Update 2

I've made some changes in order to ignore empty values of subspecification and avoiding error in back-end, here is my current code:

```
public function spacssendto(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, array(
          'product_id' => 'required',
          'subspecifications' => 'required',
        ));
        $product = Product::find($request->product_id);

        $looped = $request->subspecifications;
        $spec = [];
        foreach($looped as $loope){
            if($loope != ''){
                $spec[] = $loope;
            }
        }

        if(isset($spec)) {
            $product->subspecifications()->sync($spec, false);
        }
    }
```

this way i only get array items that have values (image #2 above).

So far so good,

#### The issue comes when I replace one of my previous choices and except being edit it will add up.

`sample`

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Any idea how i can make that replacement happen?

> PS: sync method by default does that replacement but since I've got
>   issue with empty values and provided if's in my controller now i lost
>   the ability of sync  replacement.

Comment: HTTP status 500 means that the Ajax request *did* send data, but the server responded with an error.

Comment: post your html code and backend function

Comment: @Tomalak updated my question/

Comment: @syam updated..

Comment: Check your logs what error you get on the backend.

Comment: @MarkBaijens updated with error response

Comment: Because you have a foreign key you need to add that record first (probably the missing select) So you need a default value that or just ignore that query when the value is not filled.

Comment: @MarkBaijens i would like to ignore it as you said and not to provide any default values, how can i do that?

Comment: @mafortis I'm not sure about laravel but in php you can use the isset function to check if your variable is set. If that's true run the code for the query. `if(isset($yourVariable)) { //your query code }`

Comment: @MarkBaijens laravel is php as well we can use `isset` or `try{` etc. would you mind share your idea **as code** ? I will try to convert it to laravel way see if it works

Comment: @mafortis yeah i know it's php, but I don't know if laravel has a fancy build in feature to handle these issues. The code i post to my comment is basically all i can give you without knowing details of your application. But should be enough for you to figure it out.

Comment: @MarkBaijens `1` should i use this if around `$product->subspecifications()->sync($request->subspecifications, false);` or all my controller code? `2` what would i place as `$yourVariable` ? that's why i asked for code :)

Comment: `$yourVariable` is the missing value in your query. The code you post looks like a good candidate to put inside that if statement.

Comment: @MarkBaijens thanks man I've done what you told me to and i have new issue would you mind take a look at my second update?

Comment: @mafortis It looks like you do an insert instead of an update. This is probably caused because you deleted an id from a record. Someone with more knowledge of the laravel framework can probably answer this better. I suggest opening a new question since it's a new issue. Now you have a lot of irrelevant information in your question.

Comment: @MarkBaijens thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This question is solved by 50% (Update 1) for the issue in (Update 2)
>   I've made new question [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416297/laravel-query-replace-new-data-with-old-one)

Answer (score 0):

Return code 500 means your backend code (behind your ajax call) is failing. 
What you can do is to either:

1) fix that code on the backend to handle the missing values ie if it doesn't find what it needs - handle that situation appropriately (e.g. using the default value) so it doesn't fail

2) or you can do the same on the client (js) side by filling out the missing values.
Something like:

```
    ...
          // A loop to go through all of selects.
          form.find('select.autosubspecifications').each(function() 
          {
            var selectedOption = $(this).val() || "sensible-default-value";
            spec_array.push(selectedOption);
          });
...
```