# Laravel query replace new data with old one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

> Basically this question is following of [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398643/ajax-send-selected-data-only)
>
> As that question got too messy I want to separate the question here.

## Explanation

I have appended rows in my blade where several select box will append and i can choose options of each of them. this data will save in database (**Until here everything is good**)

#### The issue

comes when I change one of my selected options and instead of being update it will add all selects as new one.

## Screenshot 1

[image: one]

## Code

`controller`

```
public function spacssendto(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, array(
          'product_id' => 'required',
          'subspecifications' => 'required',
        ));

        // get all selected option
        $looped = $request->subspecifications;
        $spec = [];
        if(!empty($looped)){ //check if there is any select box without option
          foreach($looped as $sub) {
              $sub = Subspecification::find($sub);
              if (!empty($sub->id)) {
                  $data = (
                    [
                      'product_id' => $request->product_id,
                      'subspecification_id' => $sub->id,
                    ]
                  );
                  array_push($spec, $data);
              }
          }
      }
      dd($spec);
    //   DB::table('product_subspecification')->insert($spec); // save data to database
    }
```

## Screenshot 2

results of `dd($spec)`

[image: two]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

I've changed my function to code below and now everything working fine

```
public function spacssendto(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, array(
          'product_id' => 'required',
          'subspecifications' => 'required',
        ));
        $collection = collect($request->subspecifications)->map(function ($name) {
            return strtoupper($name);
        })
        ->reject(function ($name) {
            return empty($name);
        });
      $product = Product::find($request->product_id);
      $product->subspecifications()->sync($collection);
    }
```

Hope it help others.

Comment: Need 2 days time to be able to do that.